# Fill Style is not showing

Tags: wordpress

https://www.masks4allafricans.org

here is my website link which is build using **WordPress**!! in the middle area of my homepage there is a map!! i used *interactive geo maps* free plugin for that!! nd i added custom css at the regions. but the fill color is not showing as long as i hover it!! i added my additional css in astra customisation option!!

> how can i solve that!! help please

Comment: Hi Ashik. Please show the source code (PHP/JavaScript/CSS) you have tried.

Comment: thanks for ur concern!! i solved the issue now!! i made my own custom template using html svg nd css!! thanks for ur support brother

Answer (score 0):

I really like your website. It looks like colouring countries is only possible on the pro version of the plugin. Looking at how the map is structured I don't think that applying custom CSS is going to enable you to colour each country.

You could use something like [WP Google Maps](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/) instead as that will give you a bit more customisation for free and you could use different coloured pins for each country.

Comment: thanks for ur concern!! i solved the issue now!! i made my own custom template using html svg nd css!! thanks for ur support brother